# React cant remove duplicate while adding tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i cant remove duplicate while using div/link, because i want to add link inside array(datalist.subreddit).

i noticed removing duplicate works when i delete div/link(you can look at my block comment script).

i also want to add toLowerCase, but somehow it doesnt works too.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export class Sublist extends Component {
  state = {
    dataList: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://redditclone-project.firebaseio.com/data.json", {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        const fetchedListData = [];
        for (let key in res) {
          fetchedListData.push({
            ...res[key],
            id: key
          });
        }
        this.setState({ dataList: fetchedListData });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  render() {

/*const filt = this.state.dataList.map(data => {
  return data.dataList;
}); work*/

    //didn't work
    const filt = this.state.dataList.map(data => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to={"/r/" + data.dataList.subreddit} key={data.id}>
            {data.dataList}
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    });

    const unique = [...new Set(filt.map(tag => tag.subreddit))];


    return <div>{unique}</div>;
  }
}

export default Sublist;
```

thanks

Comment: filt is an array of JSX elements how would you get subreddit property inside the filter function. an empty array will be returned always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

key must be wrapper(root) element not inner `<div key={data}>`

```
    render() {
    const unique = [
      ...new Set(this.state.dataList.map(data => data.dataList.subreddit))
    ];
    const filtered = unique.map(data => {
      return (
        <div key={data}>
          <Link to={`/r/${data}`}>
            {data}
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return <div>{filtered}</div>;
  }
```

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-mendeleev-xcrtd

Answer (score 1):

You can try reversing the order. I mean first get the unique objects and then build the JSX elements map. Hope this helps.

```
const unique = [
  ...new Set(this.state.dataList.map(data => data.dataList.subreddit))
];

const filt = unique.map(data => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={"/r/" + data.dataList.subreddit} key={data.id}>
        {data.dataList}
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: const unique = [
      ...new Set(
        this.state.dataList.map(data => data.dataList.subreddit)
      )
    ];

    const filt = unique.map(data => {
      return (
        <Link to={"/r/" + data} key={data.id}>
          /{data}
        </Link>
      );
    });

Comment: i noticed in const filt data.dataList.subreddit doesnt work, because its already mapped, so i change it into data and its work like a charm. thanks dude

Comment: Oh Ok, That's great.